# a estimative of integral with sin.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

why can i say that

\begin{equation} \int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} \frac{|\sin v|}{v}\,dv \geq \frac{1}{(k+1)\pi}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}|\sin v|\,dv, \end{equation}

This can be found on **Kreyszig's book**, function analysis, page 254. I

Comment: Because $$\frac{1}{v}\geqslant\frac{1}{(k+1)\pi}$$ for all $v\in[k\pi,(k+1)\pi]$.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

For $ k>0,$

As $ \;\;k\pi \le v \le (k+1)\pi$

we have

$$\frac{1}{v} \ge \frac{1}{(k+1)\pi}$$

and

$$\frac{|\sin(v)|}{v}\ge \frac{|\sin(v)|}{(k+1)\pi}$$